# rdlc Lookup function return byte array #Error

Tags: c#, arrays, rdlc, lookup

I want to load set of data-bound images from database dynamically in footer of a rdlc report. 
I have a `ProductDataSource` that fills from database:

```
Id of integer 
ProductImage of byte[]
```

And make appropriate `<Image> </Image>` node and add it to footer node like:

```
valueExpression = "=Lookup(" + ProductId +", Fields!Id.Value, Fields.ProductImage.Value, \"Products\")"

imageNode("Value").Value = valueExpression ;
imageNode("MIMEType").Value ="image/png"; //for exp. all images have .png extension

footerNode.Add(imageNode);
```

But image doesn't load and when i put lookup expression in a textbox just get `#Error`.

I find out from documents that [First function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251663(v=vs.90).aspx) accept `Variant or Binary` and [lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) just Variant as *result_expression*, so replace `Lookup` with `First` and it works well:

```
valueExpression = First(Fields.ProductImage.Value, "Products")
```

Also find out **Fields.ProductImage.Value(0)** gets me first byte of array

```
Lookup(Fileds!ProductId.Value, Fields!Id.Value, Fields.ProductImage.Value(0), "Products")
```

Why lookup can't return Byte array, Or in another mean, Variant is dynamic data type(Of Object), so why it can't convert byte array to Variant?

Finally after lost of trying, i solve the problem with this work around:convert byte array to Base64String and vice versa to retrieve it from Lookup() by `Convert.ToBase64String()` And `Convert.FromBase64String()`

```
    var valueExpression = "=Convert.ToBase64String(
      Lookup(" + ProductId + ",
        Fields!Id.Value,
        Convert.FromBase64String(Fields!Content.Value),
        \"TProjExeSettings\")
    )";
```

But these converting reduce report rendering speed. would you suggest better approach for add dynamically data-bound images to rdlc?

Comment: NEVER, NEVER, NEVER convert binary data to a string it will get screwed up.  Always work as byte[].  Use Encoding.UTF8 to get data from a stream to a byte[].

Comment: Tnx @jdweng I'm with you, converting to string is not good but my problem is in get byte[] from lookup(). you mean convert byte[] to UTF8?

Comment: You can't convert a byte[] to UTF8.  I meant this :  StreamReader stream = new StreamReader("filename", Encoding.UTF8);